# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in line 41 - solucion

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo este error:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\museo3\crud02\insertar.php on line 41
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a
> child row: a foreign key constraint fails (museo2.crud, CONSTRAINT
> fk_categoria FOREIGN KEY (id_categoria) REFERENCES categorias (id)) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\museo3\crud02\insertar.php:45 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\museo3\crud02\insertar.php(45):
> mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO cru...') #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\museo3\crud02\insertar.php on line 45"

ya intente muchas cosas, necesito llamar los datos de las categorías a un select para también guardarlo en la tabla principal del crud, ya lo intente pero no sirve y me confunde un poco de igual forma las tablas tiene la relación y llave foránea y me preocupe por revisar que quedara bien.

en fin este es el código del formulario:

```html
 <form method="POST" action="insertar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="localizacion" placeholder="Localizacion">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="lugar_ex" placeholder="Lugar de exhibicion">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nombre" placeholder="Titulo o Nombre">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nacionalidad" placeholder="Nacionalidad">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
         <input type="file" class="form-control mb-3" name="imagen">
</div>
 <div class="form-group">        
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="epoca" placeholder="Epoca">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="fechado" placeholder="Fechado">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="autor" placeholder="Autor">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="tipo_bien" placeholder="Tipo de bien">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="caracter_bien" placeholder="Caracter de bien">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="material" placeholder="Material">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="tecnica" placeholder="Tecnica">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="medidas" placeholder="Medidas">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="descrip" placeholder="Descripcion">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="estado" placeholder="Estado de la obra">
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="estado_inte" placeholder="Estado Integridad">
         <select name="categoria">
      <?php 
               
                $sql='SELECT * FROM categorias';
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $idcateg=$row['id'];
                    $nombrecateg=$row['nombre'];
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $idcateg?>"><?php echo $nombrecateg ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            
            ?>

         </select>


</div>
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['mensaje'])){ ?>
          <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['tipo'] ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['mensaje']; ?></strong> 
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
     </div>
<?php session_unset(); } ?>
         <input type="reset" name="Limpiar" class="btn btn-primary">
         <br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

y para continuar este es el codigo de donde estoy insertando los datos a la base de datos.

```
<?php 

include("bd.php");

if(isset($_POST['Guardar'])){
    
    $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
    $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
    $localizacion=$_POST['localizacion'];
    $lugar_ex=$_POST['lugar_ex'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $nacionalidad=$_POST['nacionalidad'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $epoca=$_POST['epoca'];
    $fechado=$_POST['fechado'];
    $autor=$_POST['autor'];
    $tipo_bien=$_POST['tipo_bien'];
    $caracter_bien=$_POST['caracter_bien'];
    $material=$_POST['material'];
    $tecnica=$_POST['tecnica'];
    $medidas=$_POST['medidas'];
    $descrip=$_POST['descrip'];
    $estado=$_POST['estado'];
    $estado_inte=$_POST['estado_inte'];
    $categoria=$_POST['categoria'];

    if(isset($imagen) && $imagen != ""){
        $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
        $temp  = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

       if( !((strpos($tipo,'png') || strpos($tipo,'jpeg') || strpos($tipo,'gif') || strpos($tipo,'webp') ||  strpos($tipo,'jpg')))){
          $_SESSION['mensaje'] = 'solo se permite archivos jpg, jpeg, png, gif y webp';
        echo "solos se permiten archivos jpg, etc ";
          $_SESSION['tipo'] = 'danger';
          header('location:ingresar.php');
       }else{ 

        $sql="SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE nombre='$categoria'";
        $queri=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($queri);
        $idcateg=$row['id'];

         $query = "INSERT INTO crud VALUES('$codigo','$ciudad','$localizacion','$lugar_ex','$nombre','$nacionalidad','$imagen','$epoca','$fechado','$autor','$tipo_bien','$caracter_bien','$material','$tecnica','$medidas','$descrip','$estado','$estado_inte','$idcateg')";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

         if($resultado){
              move_uploaded_file($temp,'imagenes/'.$imagen);   
             $_SESSION['mensaje'] = 'se ha subido correctamente';
             $_SESSION['tipo'] = 'success';
             header('location:inven.php');
         }else{
          echo "ocurrio un error";
             $_SESSION['mensaje'] = 'ocurrio un error en el servidor';
             $_SESSION['tipo'] = 'danger';
         }
       }
    }
}


?>
```

si estoy muy confundida del por que no me guarda por que la ***llave foránea*** no me lo permite, cabe aclarar la tabla es crud y la otra es categorías, las llave primaria de la tabla categorías es `id` y la llave foránea que tiene la tabla crud es `id_categoria`.

Comment: El problema muy probablemente es que el `INSERT` estaría creando un registro huérfano en la tabla relacionada, dicho de otro modo, estarías intentando insertar un valor que no existe en la tabla relacionada, por tanto, antes de insertar debes de algún modo verificar que los registros existan. La mejor forma de hacer esto, si tomas los datos de algún `select ... option` es que llenes cada `option` leyendo los datos de la base de datos. Como primer paso de depuració haz un `echo $query;` y revisa si todos los datos se están generando correctamente.

Comment: intenta con `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: todo apunta que tu `query` esta incorrecto; porque lo se? sucede de que cuando un `query` es incorrecto retorna `null` y ocurre el error de que intentan hacer un `foreach` o `while` sobre un `null` ese es el primer `warning`, luego al intentar entrar a  un indice del `array` del `row`... te va a reventar con un `faltal error` de un indice que ***no existe*** que es `null` ... como se resuelve primero valida que tu query funcione y traiga los datos ... eso lo puedes hacer ejecutandolo en `phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun el codigo el valor seleccionado de categoria seria el ID:

```
<option value="<?php echo $idcateg?>"><?php echo $nombrecateg ?></option>
```

Por lo que `$categoria=$_POST['categoria'];` estaria recibiendo el ID no el nombre, por ello no necesitarias hacer el SELECT a categoria ya que ya tienes el ID:

```
// $sql="SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE nombre='$categoria'";
// $queri=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
// $row=mysqli_fetch_array($queri);
// $idcateg=$row['id'];

// cambia $idcateg a $categoria 
$query = "INSERT INTO crud VALUES('$codigo','$ciudad','$localizacion','$lugar_ex','$nombre','$nacionalidad','$imagen','$epoca','$fechado','$autor','$tipo_bien','$caracter_bien','$material','$tecnica','$medidas','$descrip','$estado','$estado_inte','$categoria')";
```

Comment: Ay por dios si era eso :0

Comment: No me la creo, muchas graciassssssssssss